# Parsing JTokens to extract values

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON object as string in C#. I can parse it to `JObject`. Like this:

```
JObject resultObject = JObject.Parse(responseText);
```

The value of `resultObject` looks like this:

```
"mappings": {
    "car": {
        "properties": {
            "manufacturer": {
                "type": "text",
                {...}
            },
            "model": {
                "type": "text",
                {...}
            },
            "production": {
                "type": "date",
                 {...}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to map it somehow in a format like this:

```
class MyProperty {
   string Name { get; set;}
   string Type { get; set;}
}
```

Is there a convenient way to iterate over all found properties, extract name and type into a simple class like `MyProperty`?

**EDIT**

This is what I came up with so far:

Please help me find a better and more elegant way!

```
string type = "car"

JObject properties = resultObject["mappings"][type]["properties"].Value<JObject>();
List<string> keys = properties.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
// keys: ["manufacturer", "model", "production"]

foreach (string key in keys) {
    string currType = properties[key]["type"].Value<string>();

    MyProperty mypropObject = new MyProperty(){ Name = key, Type = currType };
}
```

Comment: I think you're looking at using reflection to do this, is there any way you can get the Json to come in in a different format so that you have an array of properties that you can just iterate over?

Comment: I am getting this JSON from an HTTP request, I do not have control over that format.

Comment: In which case you can use the `JObject resultObject` as it is, get the [JProperties](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm) from the car object as an `IEnumerable<JProperty>` then use a simple `properties.Select(p => new MyProperty { Name = p.Name, Type = p.Type})` to get an `IEnumerable<MyProperty>`